# Rails create a table dynamically considering another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to ruby and I'm sorry if I haven't described the issue very well :)

So, I want to know if there is a possibility in Rails for the following:
For example I have a table in which I keep some books. Let's call it Books.
This table contains the following fields: name, nr_of_pages.

How to create a table called Pages which has a number of fields equal to the value from nr_of_pages of a certain book. (the value from the Books' field is introduced by user in "new.html.erb" view)

```
Books
-----------------------
| name  | nr_of_pages |
-----------------------

Pages
-------------------------------------------------
| book_id | page_1 | page_2 | | page_3 | ...etc |
-------------------------------------------------
```

Of course Pages:

```
belongs_to :book
```

And Book:

```
has_many :pages
```

And how to fill the second table with data because these two models have different views?

Answer (score 1):

pages would actually be the page content like this:

```
Books
-----------------------
| name  | nr_of_pages |
-----------------------

Pages
-------------------------------
| book_id | page_no | content |
-------------------------------
```

Then when you create a page, you could say:

```
Page.create(content: "This is the first page of text", page_no: 1, book: some_book)
```

Then in your controller you could do something like:

```
@pages = Book.find(by_some_id).pages.order(page_no: :asc)
```

This will give you an array of pages to loop through in ascending order, giving you the ability to use an `#each` loop in your view to display all the pages.